# Is it possible to make Pages 7.1 display a list of Styles?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, pages

Is it possible to make Pages 7.1 display a list of Styles?

Every time I click a style in the list to apply it, it shows details of the style and requires additional clicks to get the list.

This makes editing a document tedious. (I am beginning to regret updating Pages)

Comment: It's probably just me (it's been a long day and I'm tired), but I don't quite follow what's happening. Are you asking because you can't apply your styles easily and just want to make it easier? Or, am I misreading your post and you just want to have the styles always visible? I ask because I can't seem to replicate what I *think* your problem is. For example, if I highlight a paragraph and then click on the styles drop-down and select an option, it is immediately applied to the paragraph without the need for additional clicks. Is Pages not working this way for you?

Comment: @Monomeeth What you describe is what used to happen. Now when I click to apply a style the list of styles disappears and I have to repeat to get the list back. Maybe I exaggerate but after doing this hundreds of times on imported text it becomes annoying

Comment: I hear ya - that'd be extremely frustrating! :( I've just checked Pages version 7.1 (5683) on three Macs (one on High Sierra and two on Sierra) and they all work fine, so it's not a version issue. Perhaps deleting the Pages preferences file will resolve this for you? As an aside, how many different styles do you use? I wonder if you can use the Shortcuts option to make life a lot easier for you? (I know, it's a workaround - not a solution - but one that may prove to be a better option if you're working on lots of imported documents).